# jQuery with AJAX only executing a part of the code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm making a web application to make customers order items, on the left side there is a element with all the current orders listed (this is actually only for the administration, but that doesnt matter right now).

On the right side there is also a element wich is empty, whenever you click one of the orders the details of that order loads in that. Im doing that with this piece of code:

```
function select_row() {
    var order_id = $(this).attr("data-order-index");
    $.ajax({
        url: "includes/functions/order.php",
        data: {order_id: order_id},
        success: function (data) {
             $("#order-information").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

I'm calling this method by doing this:

```
$("#order-list tbody tr").click(select_row);
```

Where the PHP file for that looks like:

```
echo "This is order ID: , " . $_GET['order_id'];
echo "Etc etc doesnt matter";
```

**Problem**

- The `select_row` method is very slow, it takes atleast a couple of seconds to actually load the content in the other element.

  **Is there any way to make this faster?**
- Whenever i add more code to that method (so lets say i want to make it clear that that current row is active i give it a class for giving it a specific color) it doesnt execute that code of giving the class when i put it under the `$.ajax` part. When i put the other code above the `$.ajax` part, it executes it. But it doesnt execute the `$.ajax` part.

Example:

```
function select_row() {
    var order_id = $(this).attr("data-order-index");
    $(this).addClass("selectedRow");
    $(".selectedRow", $(this).parent).removeClass("selectedRow");
    $("#delete-order-btn").prop("disabled", false);
    $.ajax({
        url: "includes/functions/order.php",
        data: {order_id: order_id},
        success: function (data) {
            $("#order-information").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**How does this come and how can i prevent it?**

Comment: If the data is taking time to appear, the issue lays with your PHP script, not JS.

Comment: ajax calls take some time to complete, depending on the Connection Speed of the user and the Band Width of the host of your website! not a jQuery problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three likely errors:

1. The value of `this` is probably not what you expect it to be
2. You are using `$(this).parent` when you probably need to be using `$(this).parent()`
3. You are setting the new selectedRow and then clearing all selectedRows.  You need to reverse that order.

In your second `select_row()` function, the value of `this` is probably not what you think it is and that is probably what is causing it to generate an error.

In javascript, the value of `this` is determined by how a function is called and a regular function call will reset `this` to either the global object (`window` in a browser) or to `undefined` if running in strict mode.  So, in your function `this` is probably `window`.

You don't show us where you are calling the `select_row()` function, but a likely solution is to pass the object that you want to operate on as an argument to `select_row()`.

It also appears that you have some faulty code as:

```
$(this).parent
```

is not a DOM element or jQuery object - it's a method reference. To get the actual parent object, you have to use this:

```
$(this).parent()
```

What I would suggest is this cleaned up code:

```
function select_row(row) {
    var item = $(row);

    // remove previous selectedRow before setting new selectedRow
    item.parent().find(".selectedRow").removeClass("selectedRow");

    // set new selected row
    item.addClass("selectedRow");

    $("#delete-order-btn").prop("disabled", false);
    $.ajax({
        url: "includes/functions/order.php",
        data: {order_id: item.attr("data-order-index")},
        success: function (data) {
            $("#order-information").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

And, then when you call `select_row`, you pass to it the new selected row.

---

As for the performance issue, that largely depends upon your backend PHP/database and the network connection between your client and your backend.  A fast Ajax call on a decent network connection where the server architecture is very responsive and returns nearly instantly with the data from cache or memory can be executed pretty quickly in well under a second.  If your database query takes a couple seconds and your server response overhead is a second or two, then the whole Ajax call starts to look like 3-5 seconds.

We really can't tell you where the time is going with the limited amount of information you've provided.  Your first step would be to quantify the exact timing of various parts of the request and see which part of the process is taking the most time.  You can use the network tab in the Chrome debugger to see the Ajax call timing from the browser's point of view and you can add some logging of timing data to your PHP file to see how much time it is taking.  The difference between the two is partly your server infrastructure (time to get the request to your PHP file and then back to the client) and partly the network transit time.

Comment: I updated my question, is it still needed to use an argument for this? Or can i do it without? Btw about the `.parent()` method: My ide gives me an error when im using the `()` after it. It tells me it needs 1 parameter.

About the speed of the snippet, after i replaced mine with yours, it works alot faster for some reason. So thank you.

Comment: @Bas - If `select_row` is passed directly to a click handler like you show, then you can use `this` as a reference to the element that was clicked on.  Your IDE is just wrong about `.parent()`.  If you look at the [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/parent/), it has one `optional` argument and you must call it with `()` in order to execute it.